# Why MainClass is not coming out from waiting state

Tags: java, wait, notify

In below code why the part after the wait() is not going to execute.
Even if notify() is there in the object whose lock owned by the main thread.

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo dm = new Demo();
        dm.add();

        synchronized (dm) {
            try {
                System.out.println("going to wait");
                dm.wait();
                System.out.println("after wait");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(dm.result);              
        }
    }
}

class Demo  {
    int result;

    public void add(){
        System.out.println("in demo");
        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.println("in demo syn block");
            for(int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
                result=i+result;                
            }
            System.out.println("IN demo:"+result);
            notify();       
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I need to know is-why the code after wait() is not executing even if notify() is there.If i try to solve this using thread then the wait() get out of it's state automatically.

Comment: Any `wait`s that come after a `notify` aren't affected. It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Your program is single-threaded.

Comment: wait() and notify() not used with thread instances..if i try to do with threads then the wait() coming out waiting state automatically

Comment: You can have a multithreaded program and not use `wait` and `notify` with their corresponding `Thread` objects.

Comment: can u do it??i am getting confused....yesterday i tried

Comment: Re, "If i try to solve this using thread then..."  If you try to solve _what_?  What do you want the program to do?

Comment: I just want to see how wait and notify works in a simple manner..In most of the books wait is initialized with thread instances..in the above program i want main thread to wait while Demo for loop completes its work and the statements after wait get executed as soon as notify() comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which you are calling is wrong.

1. First You call `dm.add();` method of `Demo` class from `main` Thread.
2. This method will take the lock of `Demo` object  and do the task and finish.
3. Then you are taking the lock of `dm` object in Main Thread and started waiting on it.

So what is Happening Here is You are waiting and no one is notifying then. So Your code will never execute written after `wait` statement